# Textview size needs to change according to user's given value in EditText

Tags: java, android

Dynamically change the TextView size based on user input. If user changes the value, `textview` needs to change

```
     et0=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText0);
     bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

     bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String text = ((et.getText().toString()));
                    float i=et0.getTextSize();

                    tv.setText(text);
                    tv.setTextSize(i) ; 
        }
    }

//problem is value is changing one time if edit again text size is not changing
any help advance thanks
```

Comment: here on button click, your textview text size will be set as equal to your edittext text size. what do you actually want? please explain a little more.

Comment: I have 2 ediText box user enter text in 1 st editTextbox ex :"ABCD" size Ex:18 the Textview Text size need to be

Comment: size need to be enter 18 in another editText so the textview display Text according to the user input

Comment: in that case see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

One way to resolve your issue is by attaching a listener to the editText box.

Here's an example [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) implementation:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
       if(!s.equals("") )
            { //do your work here }
       }

   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

   }

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

   }
});
```

You can have a little size check inside `onTextChanged`. Once it reaches a certain breakpoint, you increase the size of the text. :-)

Comment: see 2 editText box one i am entring text "ABC" another one i am entring "15" button click Textview size need to change 15 for ABC which is display in TextView

Comment: textview  need to display ABC and ABC size should be 15 , if you change the value 15 to 20 "ABC" Size  need to change again

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a variable so that it takes whatever the user gives you and uses that value as its set text size. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

To change the `textView` text size equal to the `editText` input value, use this:

```
 bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String text = ((et.getText().toString()));  //number input

                    Float f= Float.parseFloat(text);  // setting the input number as textview text size
                    tv.setText(text);
                    tv.setTextSize(f) ; 
        }
    }
```

Note: `editText` input value must be a number

Comment: Process: com.example.chetan.ninepatchimages, PID: 4372
                                                                                  java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "fyuu"
                                                                                      at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)

Comment: use two edittext one for the texts and the other for the text size. and in the text size edittext enter only number, otherwise the same error you will find. numberformateexception

Comment: 1st EditText  have a value "ABC" second i am passsing text size ex:"10"

Comment: button click TextView show ABC and that size shuld be 15  if i again change 15 to 20 "ABC" change size of texview  to 20

Answer (score 0):

In your xml

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtText"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtOutput"/>
```

and implement textwatcher over edittext

```
      edtText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                txtOutput.setText(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        et0=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText0);
        bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
   

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String gttext = ((et.getText().toString()));

                int s = Integer.parseInt(et0.getText().toString().trim());

                tv.setText(gttext);
                tv.setTextSize(s) ;
            }
        });